# How do I catch specific exceptions from pygresql?

Tags: python, pygresql

I'm trying to improve my error handling, Particularly I would like to handle IntegrityError exceptions from pygresql.

I'm getting the error "NameError: name 'IntegrityError' is not defined" so I need to import something. Is this possible? What do I need to import?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible and almost always advisable to catch the specific exceptions that are thrown by modules you're using.

You're correct that you need to import that specific exception from the package you're using, as it's not part of the python built in exceptions.

Looking at the `pygresql` [docs (around p.88)](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygresql/stable/pygresql.pdf#page=90&zoom=100,0,169), it seems that most exceptions are raised from the `pgdb` module.

Potentially;

```
from pgdb import IntegrityError

# more code...

try:
  db.insert(obj) # or whatever data access methods you have
except IntegrityError as e:
  # handle the exception
  print(str(e))
```

Or it maybe the `pgdb` module is inside the `pygresql` module so it might be `from pygresql.pgdb import IntegrityError`. The actual import path may vary, but the syntax will be as above.

Comment: That was the first thing I niavely I tried, but it doesn't work. The problem isn't that I don't know the syntax of import, it's that I don't know WHAT to import.

Comment: I'm looking through the docs and even into a [mirror of the source](https://github.com/Cito/PyGreSQL) and there's really poor documentation and the source code offers very little explanation of where the exceptions are raised. Worst case you can `except Exception as e` and then in the block, check its type by `if type(e).__name__ == IntegrityError` - make sure to add an `else` block with a `raise` that will re-raise other exceptions and allow them to bubble up and not just fail silently! Alternatively switch to [`sqlalchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)!

Comment: Unfortunately, if it where better documented, I wouldn't have needed to post. Asking on SE is normally only after I've exausted everything else I can think of. I have no desire what-so-ever to convert an existing codebase to use sqlalchemy, I'm more likely to just abandon the improvements I'm working on.

Comment: The pgdb module implements the DB API 2 standard according to the docs. So importing the exceptions from that module should work, because it is part of the DB API 2 specification. If it does not work for you, please report a bug (https://github.com/Cito/PyGreSQL/issues) and add the details on the platform, Python and PyGreSQL version, and how you installed it, and what error message you got when importing that way.

Comment: Btw. the documentation is here: http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pgdb/module.html#errors-raised-by-this-module

Answer (score 0):

After the better part of a day mucking about with this I was able to figure out that the exceptions are defined in the Connection object in pgdb (even if you're using the pg interface). In this case I'm using Flask's @app.errorhandler decorator, but it should still show what needs imported and and how to use it.

```
from pgdb import Connection

@app.errorhandler(Connection.IntegrityError)
def handle_IntegrityError(e):
  return(str(e), 409)
```

It would be helpful if pygresql factored these out, as it would make it a lot less confusing.

Comment: The exceptions exist on the connection class and instance for convenience, but they should also exist on the module, i.e. `from pgdb import IntegrityError` should work. This is part of the DB API 2 standard. If it does not work for you (for me, it does, please report a bug on GitHub (https://github.com/Cito/PyGreSQL/issues) or on the mailing list.